# MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
Router.get('/vrs', (request, response) => {

response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../public/webPage/VRS", "index.html"))
})
```

I  try to load index.html file..this index.html connect a lot of css and js file..
console error:mapmatching:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:200/dashboard/css/leaflet.css?v=0.7.3' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I only got the error displaying the css files when i run in my localhost:200 (Node.js) but not in my normal index.html file.

```
index.html
<script async src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b83642ccaf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font- 
     awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.6777faf8.css"></head>

   <body>
   script defer src="markeraws.867791c5.js"></script> <script defer src="hotline.2437072b.js">
   </script>  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tangram@0.20.1/dist/tangram.min.js"></script> 
  <script defer src="js.19383176.js"></script> 
</body>
```

checked the spelling of my css file name: no issue on the name or the css path

i have search all over the internet, but nothing helps. It might be i configured it wrongly since i am not really familiar with the config, but i don't have any ideas. Any helps or hints area really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: <body>
   script defer src="markeraws.867791c5.js"></script> check your syntax

Comment: hi plz can you explain for me

Comment: Your first script tag doesnt have have '<' in the start ! Did you correct it ?